# "It more makes sense that he's there" Vs. "It makes sense more, that he's there"

Tags: verbs, comparative-constructions

What's the correct choice among the following choices?  I have a doubt about where to place the adjective "more" in this verbal sentence (unlike in nominative sentences that I know that I have to put it before a noun. `e.g. "more amazing"`.).

> "It **more** makes sense that he's there"

Or

> "It makes sense **more**, that he's there"

Answer (score 2):

> It makes **more** sense that he's here.

See the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20makes%20sense%2C%20makes%20sense%20more%2C%20makes%20more%20sense&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20makes%20sense%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmakes%20sense%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmakes%20more%20sense%3B%2Cc0):

[image]